# Issue with m3u8 files - separate audio and video

Tags: m3u8, m3u

I've downloaded a m3u8 file, I noticed two files which were strange to me.

Upon loading it I noticed one was just video and the other audio.

What would be the best way of merging the two? Would I need to completely recode my application or is there a feature within the m3u8 file that can do the job?

File 1:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:301
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="1617045851-6687-0-init.m4s"
#EXTINF:6.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T19:54:22.000+0000
1617045851-6687-0-00301.m4s
#EXTINF:6.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T19:54:28.000+0000
1617045851-6687-0-00302.m4s
#EXTINF:6.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T19:54:34.000+0000
1617045851-6687-0-00303.m4s
#EXTINF:6.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T19:54:40.000+0000
1617045851-6687-0-00304.m4s
#EXTINF:6.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T19:54:46.000+0000
1617045851-6687-0-00305.m4s
```

File 2:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:389
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="1617045851-6687-3-init.m4s"
#EXTINF:5.994667,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T20:03:09.939+0000
1617045851-6687-3-00389.m4s
#EXTINF:5.994667,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T20:03:15.933+0000
1617045851-6687-3-00390.m4s
#EXTINF:5.994667,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T20:03:21.928+0000
1617045851-6687-3-00391.m4s
#EXTINF:6.016000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T20:03:27.923+0000
1617045851-6687-3-00392.m4s
#EXTINF:5.994667,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-03-29T20:03:33.939+0000
1617045851-6687-3-00393.m4s
```

Much appreciated,
Ali

Comment: As far as i know, you can just paste the body of one m3u8 file into another if you keep the header intact.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by "merging" the two -- what is your use case?